# Consume WCF service from Coldfusion 7

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, coldfusion, wsdl

I am trying to figure out a way to consume a WCF service I have (wsdl) from Coldfusion.  I need to pass values in the request header.  I can't seem to find any good examples anywhere.  Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the functions you want is

```
AddSOAPRequestHeader(webservice, namespace, name, value [, mustunderstand])
AddSOAPResponseHeader(namespace, name, value[, mustunderstand])
```

These let you add XML to the request and response headers of your webservice.

Comment: That's the stuff!  Docs:  http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000379.htm

Answer (score 0):

In ColdFusion you can consume webservices using cfinvoke

```
<cfinvoke  
webservice="http://www.somewebservice.com/WebService.wsdl" 
method="getWebServiceMethod" 
returnvariable="webServiceResult"> 
<cfinvokeargument name="arg1" value="Arg1"/> 
<cfinvokeargument name="arg2" value="Arg2"/> 
</cfinvoke> 
<cfoutput>The Result is #webServiceResult#</cfoutput>
```

or CreateObject

```
<cfscript> 
ws = CreateObject("webservice",  
"http://www.somewebservice.com/WebService.wsdl"); 
webServiceResult = ws.getWebServiceMethod("Arg1","Arg2"); 
writeoutput(webServiceResult); 
</cfscript>
```

Comment: The key part was the "request headers".  I need to send a couple values in the request header.

Comment: What kind of headers? Could you call the service via cfhttp and send headers with cfhttpparam type="header"? There is also a addSOAPRequestHeader Function but never tried it with a WCF Service.